# Why justifying with execCommand does not work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, execcommand

Why justifying with execCommand does not work properly? check the below code:

```js
$('#JustifyLeft').click(function(){
    document.execCommand("JustifyLeft", false, "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Select whole text and click the button</p>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="TRUE" style="font-size: 27px; text-align: center;">
  
<span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;">Hi<span style="font-size: 35px;">I</span>am<span style="font-size: 18px;">Blah Blah</span>Ok</span>
</div>

<input type="button" id="JustifyLeft" value="Align Left">
```

After selecting the whole text and Justifying it you will see the underlines only remained on `<text>` nodes and `<span>` nodes have not text-decoration.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

If you will look onto element structure in developer tool you will see execCommand is adding closing `</span>` after ***Hi, am and Ok*** and wrapping it with a `<div>`Like below

```
    <div style="text-align: left;">
    <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Hi</span>
    <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 35px;">I</span>
    <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">am</span>
    <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Blah Blah</span>
    <span style="font-style: italic; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Ok</span>
    </div>
```

You can correct it by just changing your first `<span>` to `<div>` like below

```
<div style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline;">Hi
<span style="font-size: 35px;">I</span>am
<span style="font-size: 18px;">Blah Blah</span>Ok
</div>
```